# How to fix a concrete crack on interior wall?

Tags: concrete, repair, crack, interior

Help! Concrete crack on interior wall.

Situation:

- bedroom
- poured concrete walls (40 years old)
- high rise building in a high humid climate, high floor.
- no issue or threat of water damage
- crack is about 1m in length
- runs parallel to the ceiling line, about 50 cm below.
- crack had about 3 layers of plaster over it from previous renovations.

I’m trying to figure out the best way to proceed in patching the crack before I mud over and paint.

Any advice on how to fix will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Pictures would help. Do you know if any other apartments have similar issues?

Comment: Do you own or rent? Usually if it's a rental, it's up to the landlord to do repairs like this. That may vary depending on locale. Based on your user name, I'd guess you live in Macau, but it would be helpful to make that explicit...

Comment: I own the flat so it’s on us to conduct the repair.  You’re correct in that it is in Macau

Comment: I’ll try to get a photo up

Comment: I hadn’t heard of other issues in other flats. But most of our neighbors have done extensive renovations and we are one of the few remaining with original wall work.  The building did sustain several direct hits from strong typhoons in the past 7 years so it’s possible the crack occurred from the stress in flexing and twisting in the wind

Comment: https://share.icloud.com/photos/081Tg3uWt4zDzWLXlEk-Qi-ng  I can’t get stackex to upload the photo so here is a link.